# Pandas - groupby and show aggregate on all "levels"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am a Pandas newbie and I am trying to automate the processing of ticket data we get from our IT ticketing system.  After experimenting I was able to get 80 percent of the way to the result I am looking for.

Currently I pull in the ticket data from a CSV into a "df" dataframe.  I then want to summarize the data for the higher ups to review and get high level info like totals and average "age" of tickets (number of days between ticket creation date and current date).

Here's an example of the ticket data for "df" dataframe:

[image]

I then create "df2" dataframe to summarize df using:

```
df2 =  df.groupby(["dept", "group", "assignee", "ticket_type"]).agg(task_count=('ticket_type', 'size'), mean_age_in_days=('age', 'mean'),)
```

And here's what it I am getting if I print out df2...which is very close to what I need.

[image]

As you can see we look at the count of tickets assigned to each staff member, separated by type (incident, request), and also look at the average "age" of each ticket type (incident, request) for each staff member.

The roadblock that I am hitting now and have been pulling my hair out about is I need to show the aggregates (count and averages of ages) at all 3 levels (sorry if I am using the wrong jargon).  Basically I need to show the count and average age for all tickets associated with a group, then the same thing for tickets at the department ("Division") level, and lastly the grand total and grand average in green...for all tickets which is the entire organization (all tickets in all departments, groups).

Here's an example of the ideal result I am trying to get:

[image]

You will see in red I want the count of tickets and average age for tickets for a given group.  Then, in blue I want the count and average age for all tickets on the dept/division level (all tickets for all groups belonging to a given dept./division).  Lastly, I want the grand total and grand average for all tickets in the entire organization.  In the end both the df2 (summary of ticket data) and df will be dumped to an Excel file on separate worksheets in the same workbook.

Please have mercy on me!  Can someone show me how I could generate the desired "summary" with counts and average age at all levels (group, dept., and organization)?  Thanks in advance for any assistance, I'd really, really appreciate it!

*Added link to CSV with sample ticket data below:
[on Github](https://github.com/b4ckplane/sample_ticket_data/blob/main/sample_ticket_data.csv)

Also, here's raw CSV text for the sample ticket data:

```
,number,created_on,dept,group,assignee,ticket_type,age
0,14500,2021-02-19 11:48:28,IT_Services_Division,Helpdesk,Jane Doe,Incident,361
1,16890,2021-04-20 10:51:49,IT_Services_Division,Helpdesk,Jane Doe,Incident,120
2,16891,2021-04-20 11:51:00,IT_Services_Division,Helpdesk,Tilly James,Request,120
3,15700,2021-06-09 09:05:28,IT_Services_Division,Systems,Steve Lee,Incident,252
4,16000,2021-08-12 09:32:39,IT_Services_Division,Systems,Linda Nguyen,Request,188
5,16100,2021-08-18 17:43:54,IT_Services_Division,TechSupport,Joseph Wills,Incident,181
6,19000,2021-01-17 15:01:50,IT_Services_Division,TechSupport,Bill Gonzales,Request,30
7,18990,2021-01-10 13:00:01,IT_Services_Division,TechSupport,Bill Gonzales,Request,37
8,18800,2021-12-03 21:13:12,Data_Division,DataGroup,Bob Simpson,Incident,74
9,16880,2021-10-18 11:56:03,Data_Division,DataGroup,Bob Simpson,Request,119
10,18000,2021-11-09 14:28:44,IT_Services_Division,Systems,Veronica Paulson,Incident,98
```

Comment: i can help. but post a sample of the first image as a raw CSV text (not parsed df). also, what format do you want the output in? your last image is an image. do you want the output as an image or... ?

Comment: Thanks @Joshua!  I edited my post to have the raw CSV text for the sample ticket data.  I want the output as an Excel file with one worksheet/tab with the "summarized" df2 data and a second worksheet/tab with the "df" data (listing of all tickets unsummarized).

Comment: Excel is a proprietary tool/format and can be done using openpyxl. but you'll be more likely to get help with open source formats like CSV and JSON around here. your data seems like a perfect candidate for the JSON format. Have you heard of it? [It looks very nice when pretty-printed like this.](https://devnote.in/how-to-prettyprint-the-json-file-in-python/) Let me know if you want it in JSON. I can do that.

Comment: Thanks again @Joshua.  Actually CSV is good.  Could you do both CSV and JSON?  The people consuming the report in the end will literally be opening the CSV to view on their desktops  :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a different approach which is easier, but results in a different structure

```
agg_df = df.copy()

#Add dept-level info to the department
gb = agg_df.groupby('dept')
task_counts = gb['ticket_type'].transform('count').astype(str)
mean_ages = gb['age'].transform('mean').round(2).astype(str)
agg_df['dept'] += ' ['+task_counts+' tasks, avg age= '+mean_ages+']'

#Add group-level info to the group label
gb = agg_df.groupby(['dept','group'])
task_counts = gb['ticket_type'].transform('count').astype(str)
mean_ages = gb['age'].transform('mean').round(2).astype(str)
agg_df['group'] += ' ['+task_counts+' tasks, avg age= '+mean_ages+']'

#Add org-level info
agg_df['org'] = 'Org [{} tasks, avg age = {}]'.format(len(agg_df),agg_df['age'].mean().round(2))

agg_df = (
    agg_df.groupby(['org','dept','group','assignee','ticket_type']).agg(
        task_count=('ticket_type','count'),
        mean_ticket_age=('age','mean'))
)

agg_df
```

[image]

Comment: You are awesome @mitoRibo. Thanks so much!  This formatting is actually nicer than my original approach/layout.  I tested it already with my live data and it works!

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't think of a cleaner way to get the structure you want and had to manually loop through the different groupby levels adding one row at a time

```
multi_ind = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([],names=('dept','group','assignee','ticket_type'))
agg_df = pd.DataFrame(index=multi_ind, columns=['task_count','mean_age_in_days'])

data = lambda df: {'task_count':len(df),'mean_age_in_days':df['age'].mean()}

for dept,dept_g in df.groupby('dept'):
    for group,group_g in dept_g.groupby('group'):
        for assignee,assignee_g in group_g.groupby('assignee'):
            for ticket_type,ticket_g in assignee_g.groupby('ticket_type'):
                
                #Add ticket totals
                agg_df.loc[(dept,group,assignee,ticket_type)] = data(ticket_g)
        
        #Add group totals
        agg_df.loc[(dept,group,assignee,'Group Total/Avg')] = data(group_g)
        
    #Add dept totals
    agg_df.loc[(dept,group,assignee,'Dept Total/Avg')] = data(dept_g)

#Add org totals
agg_df.loc[('','','','Org Total/Avg')] = data(df)

agg_df
```

Output

[image]

Comment: This was also nice!  Appreciate you for providing multiple approaches @mitoRibo!  For some reason I get error testing this approach with my live data.  I should mention in my live table the "group" column is actually named "assignment_group" and the "assignee" is named "assigned_to" in the live system.  I get error saying: "agg_df.loc[(dept,assignment_group,assigned_to,sys_class_name)] = data(ticket_g)
NameError: name 'assignment_group' is not defined".  Not sure what's going on but I will go with your other answer for now :).